# Les Miserables Co-occurrence

Tags: d3.js

Can some one please explain `GROUP`,`SOURCE`,`VALUE` and `TARGET` in **Les Misérables Co-occurrence matrix** and how they are **interlinked**.

- It would b every helpful if the explanation is done through an example.

I tried the existing example by taking 5 characters, but could not link the **source**, **target** and **values**.

Also if any one has tried other input data(json data)  than the standard example 'miserables.json' please share so that i can get good understanding to put my data and see the visualization.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The only things interlinked are source and target, which denote indices into the array of nodes. There're plenty of force directed layout examples, including ones with other data.

Comment: Hi @Lars ,I wanted to know how **Group** from **nodes** and **source** ,**target** ,**values** from **links** interconnected in the following json example present in the link,http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/miserables.json.

Comment: From miserables.json data example,let us consider only first 5names, now how are the first 5 names linked to **source**,**Target** and **Value**?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Source and target are set for links, not nodes.

Comment: Hi Lars,that much i understood,but what is the relation between **group** in nodes and source,Target and Value in links? Since iam creating a new json file of my own data i wanted to know how i should assign values to each of the fields present in **nodes** and **links**. Hope am clear with my question.

Comment: There is no relation. The group refers to the group of the character.

Comment: i would understand much if the following data is explained, **"name":"Myriel","group":1** and **"source":1,"target":0,"value":1**. How are the values in group,source,target and value changed?

Comment: As I've said, source and target are indices. Group and value can be whatever you want them to be.

Comment: Thank You very much Lars, i have gained a little more  from your answers. A last question on this, "source":1,"target":0,"value":1, from where exactly do i get  **source** and **target**  values,because i see repeated values for both. My understanding is source  is page number and target is the number of times the character present in that page. Please clarify on this.

Comment: No, these are links between characters -- as I've said, the numbers are indices into the array of nodes, i.e. 0 stands for the first node, 1 for the second etc.

Comment: HI Lars,is there any specific value for colors? i am getting most of the cells as black and i want to change to different colors.

Comment: You set the color in your code. You can use something in the data for it, but don't have to.

Comment: Hi Lars,from my data(retail Scenario) i am feeding **source** and **target** as customer names and **value** as products(product id) used by the customer.                                                        The challenge is, i have to display product id  when the mouse is pointed on the color.Can that be done within this code?  miserables.links.forEach(function(link) {
matrix[link.source][link.target].z += link.value;
matrix[link.target][link.source].z += link.value;
matrix[link.source][link.source].z += link.value;
matrix[link.target][link.target].z += link.value;});

Comment: Please have a look at the examples that are on the website and elsewhere. What you're asking for is a tooltip and there are many examples and questions on this.

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff, wen iam trying to upload the json file to the matrix i am getting node not defined error ,after this code **node.append("text")**. pls let me knw is it bcoz of json file or some other err. thanks

Answer (score 6):

I was also interested in this task, and here's what I came up with. First I created the json that would be fed into the visualization, using Python ([sample json](http://tdm-api-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/json/king_henry_the_fifth.json)). The json should have the following form:

```
{ "nodes": [
            {"name":node_name, "group":node_group},
            {"name":another_node_name, "group":another_node_group}, ...
],
  "links":[
            {"source"link_source, "target":link_target, "value":link_value,
            {"source"another_link_source, "target":another_link_target, "value":another_link_value}, ...
]
}
```

Then it's just a matter of pointing your application to your json files. I used Python's Flask library to create a simple server that could serve my json files:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response
from flask.ext.cors import CORS
import json

application = Flask(__name__)

# Utilize CORS to allow cross-origin API requests
cors = CORS(application)

#############################
# Network Visualization App #
#############################

@application.route('/api/json/<request>', methods=['GET'])
def parse_json_request(request):
    with open("json/" + request, 'r') as json_in:
        cooccurrence_json = json.load(json_in)
        return jsonify(cooccurrence_json)

@application.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return "Sorry, the page you requested could not be found."  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True)
```

I then uploaded the server and my json to Amazon Web Services, used [this Elastic Beanstalk tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) to deploy the application, and modified the javascript code in the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ocks-org do-not-copy">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dramatic Co-occurrence</title>
<style>
    @import url(../style.css?aea6f0a);
    d3_plot {
        font-size: 80%;
    }

    body.svg {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .background {
        fill: #eee;
    }

    line {
        stroke: #fff;
    }

    text.active {
        fill: red;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js?2.8.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>


<header>
</header>

<h1>Character Co-occurrence in Shakespearean Drama</h1>

<aside style="margin-top:20px;">
    <p>Play:
        <select id="selected_json">
            <option value='"http://tdm-api-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/json/king_henry_the_fifth.json"'>Henry VIII</option>
            <option value='"http://tdm-api-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/json/romeo_and_juliet.json"'>Romeo and Juliet</option>
            <option value='"http://tdm-api-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/json/hamlet.json"'>Hamlet</option>
        </select>

    <i>      </i>

    Order:
        <select id="order">
            <option value="name">by Name</option>
            <option value="count">by Frequency</option>
            <option value="group">by Cluster</option>
        </select>



        <p>This application visualizes the degree to which characters in Shakespeare's plays appear together.

            <p>Each colored cell represents two characters that appeared in the same scene, and darker cells indicate characters that co-occurred more frequently.

                <p>Use the drop-down menus to select a different play, reorder the matrix, and explore the data.

                    <p>Built with data from ProQuest's Chadwyck Healey <a href="http://www.proquest.com/products-services/literature_online.html">Literature Online Collections</a>.
</aside>

<d3_plot></d3_plot>

<script>

    function select_json(new_json) {

    var margin = {
            top: 120,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 10,
            left: 160
        },
        width = 800,
        height = 800;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, width]),
        z = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 4]).clamp(true),
        c = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(10));

    var svg = d3.select("d3_plot").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .style("margin-left", "0px")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");    

        // Based on the user-selected input text above, make the appropriate api call and retrieve the json 
        d3.json(new_json, function(miserables) {

            console.log(new_json)

            var matrix = [],
                nodes = miserables.nodes,
                n = nodes.length;

            // Compute index per node.
            nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
                node.index = i;
                node.count = 0;
                matrix[i] = d3.range(n).map(function(j) {
                    return {
                        x: j,
                        y: i,
                        z: 0
                    };
                });
            });

            // Convert links to matrix; count character occurrences.
            miserables.links.forEach(function(link) {
                matrix[link.source][link.target].z += link.value;
                matrix[link.target][link.source].z += link.value;
                matrix[link.source][link.source].z += link.value;
                matrix[link.target][link.target].z += link.value;
                nodes[link.source].count += link.value;
                nodes[link.target].count += link.value;
            });

            // Precompute the orders.
            var orders = {
                name: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) {
                    return d3.ascending(nodes[a].name, nodes[b].name);
                }),
                count: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) {
                    return nodes[b].count - nodes[a].count;
                }),
                group: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) {
                    return nodes[b].group - nodes[a].group;
                })
            };

            // The default sort order.
            x.domain(orders.name);

            svg.append("rect")
                .attr("class", "background")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            var row = svg.selectAll(".row")
                .data(matrix)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "row")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                    return "translate(0," + x(i) + ")";
                })
                .each(row);

            row.append("line")
                .attr("x2", width);

            row.append("text")
                .attr("x", -6)
                .attr("y", x.rangeBand() / 2)
                .attr("dy", ".32em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                .text(function(d, i) {
                    return nodes[i].name;
                });

            var column = svg.selectAll(".column")
                .data(matrix)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "column")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                    return "translate(" + x(i) + ")rotate(-90)";
                });

            column.append("line")
                .attr("x1", -width);

            column.append("text")
                .attr("x", 6)
                .attr("y", x.rangeBand() / 2)
                .attr("dy", ".32em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                .text(function(d, i) {
                    return nodes[i].name;
                });

            function row(row) {
                var cell = d3.select(this).selectAll(".cell")
                    .data(row.filter(function(d) {
                        return d.z;
                    }))
                    .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "cell")
                    .attr("x", function(d) {
                        return x(d.x);
                    })
                    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                    .attr("height", x.rangeBand())
                    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
                        return z(d.z);
                    })
                    .style("fill", function(d) {
                        return nodes[d.x].group == nodes[d.y].group ? c(nodes[d.x].group) : null;
                    })
                    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                    .on("mouseout", mouseout);
            }

            function mouseover(p) {
                d3.selectAll(".row text").classed("active", function(d, i) {
                    return i == p.y;
                });
                d3.selectAll(".column text").classed("active", function(d, i) {
                    return i == p.x;
                });
            }

            function mouseout() {
                d3.selectAll("text").classed("active", false);
            }

            d3.select("#order").on("change", function() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                order(this.value);
            });

            function order(value) {
                x.domain(orders[value]);

                var t = svg.transition().duration(2500);

                t.selectAll(".row")
                    .delay(function(d, i) {
                        return x(i) * 4;
                    })
                    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                        return "translate(0," + x(i) + ")";
                    })
                    .selectAll(".cell")
                    .delay(function(d) {
                        return x(d.x) * 4;
                    })
                    .attr("x", function(d) {
                        return x(d.x);
                    });

                t.selectAll(".column")
                    .delay(function(d, i) {
                        return x(i) * 4;
                    })
                    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                        return "translate(" + x(i) + ")rotate(-90)";
                    });
            }

            var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                order("group");
                d3.select("#order").property("selectedIndex", 2).node().focus();
            }, 5000);
        });


    }

    // set initial json selection
    select_json("http://tdm-api-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/json/king_henry_the_fifth.json");

    // handle on click event
    d3.select('#selected_json').on('change', function() {

            // erase old image
            d3.select("svg").remove(); 

            var new_json = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
            select_json(new_json);
        });
</script>

  [1]: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html
```

This produced a webpage that looks like the image below, which you can see in action [here](http://tdm-api-pq.github.io/). I hope this helps others!

P.S. While making the page, I found it extremely helpful to open my html in Chrome, then use `more tools --> developer tools` to help me debug errors in the javascript.

[image]

Comment: Nice one @duhaime.

Comment: your app seems not work on both firefox and chrome; also in my hands your code with the miserables.json returns error `TypeError: matrix[link.source] is undefined`

Comment: Sorry @DimaLituiev, this app is no longer hosted. I have a version of this app running here though: http://douglasduhaime.com/

Comment: Can you explain what "value" means in the data set? I understand "group", "target" and "source", but I still don't know what value means.

Comment: "value" here just indicates the strength of the connection between two nodes. In this particular chart, value indicates the total number of times two characters appear within the same Act of a play. In other contexts though, you'll see the same data structure used but "value" will have a different meaning (for example, value could indicate the number of love letters character A sent character B). The more technical term for "value" in the network literature is "edge weight". I hope that helps @chinloyal!

Comment: Thank you that does help @duhaime

Comment: [douglasduhaime.com](https://douglasduhaime.com) was well worth a detour. Lovely resource, with some impressive work.