# Understanding Les Miserables Co-occurrence data

Tags: d3.js, graph

Working with the Les Miserables Co-occurrence data, I did some research (including [Les Miserables Co-occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463614/les-miserables-co-occurrence)) but still hoping someone can help to confirm my understanding.

For example, the data is in json format, here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/christophergandrud/d3Network/master/JSONdata/miserables.json

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

This is how I see it:

*Nodes:*

There are 77 names, in 11 groups (from 0 to 10). The grouping is fixed. Seems these names have corresponding codes but not being indicated anywhere.

*Links:*

Source and Targets, are represented by codes 0 ~ 76 (so 77 in total).

Value here, refers to the number of times occurred. for example, {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8} refers to Mlle.Baptistine to Myriel occurred 8 times (if the names are coded in sequence?)

Am I getting them right? What's the full explanation of this data? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're right, the link `{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1}` (the first one) means that `Myriel` and `Napoleon` were cited together in the same chapter; and the link `{"source":2,"target":0,"value":8}` (the second one) means that `Mlle.Baptistine` and `Myriel` were cited together in 8 (distinct) chapters.

So you're also right regarding to the nodes : they don't have explicit id, but the links refer to them using their indexes in the `nodes` array.

The `group` id is a cluster id, obtained from some community-detection algorithm.